# How do I end a a django process with a bash script?

Tags: python, linux, django, bash, shell

I wrote a bash script to start a django process, however, I want to be able to end the django process while it's running with a bash script as well. I'm writing a web app for Koding.com that starts a django process in an online terminal linked to the user's personal VM by running a bash script with a press of a button, and I want users to be able to end the process with a press of a button as well. I know that control C would end the process, but I haven't been able to find out how to do that in a bash script. How could I go about doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Pass pidfile=< path_to_file > argument to manage.py, e.g.

`manage.py runfcgi pidfile=/var/run/myapp.pid`

This file will contains process id of your application. You should add something like

```
kill $(cat /var/run/myapp.pid)
```

to your stop function in bash script.